# PHP paypal commerce platform(api v2) partner is not getting paid?

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-marketplaces

Paypal Commerce platform in php order capture partner is not getting paid and seller is getting full amount. What should I send in order capture?

Below is the array I am sending in 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders'

```
Array
(
    [intent] => CAPTURE
    [purchase_units] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference_id] => 
                    [description] => Darshan Shah 70099
                    [custom_id] => 10541
                    [soft_descriptor] => 
                    [invoice_id] => SELLERINV-70099
                    [amount] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => USD
                            [value] => 105
                            [breakdown] => Array
                                (
                                    [item_total] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => USD
                                            [value] => 100
                                        )
                                    [shipping] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => USD
                                            [value] => 5
                                        )
                                    [tax_total] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => USD
                                            [value] => 0
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Test Product K
                                    [description] => Test Product K
                                    [unit_amount] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => USD
                                            [value] => 50
                                        )
                                    [tax] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => USD
                                            [value] => 0
                                        )
                                    [quantity] => 2
                                    [category] => DIGITAL_GOODS
                                )
                        )
                    [payee] => Array
                        (
                            [merchant_id] => 
                        )
                    [shipping] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [full_name] => Darshan Shah
                                )
                            [address] => Array
                                (
                                    [address_line_1] => 5/11 G1 Rajalakshmi Enclave
                                    [address_line_2] => 
                                    [admin_area_2] => Middleton Grange
                                    [admin_area_1] => CON
                                    [postal_code] => 111111
                                    [country_code] => GB
                                )
                        )
                    [payment_instruction] => Array
                        (
                            [disbursement_mode] => INSTANT
                            [platform_fees] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [amount] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [currency_code] => USD
                                                    [value] => 5
                                                )
                                            [payee] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [merchant_id] => 
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [application_context] => Array
        (
            [brand_name] => 
            [locale] => en-US
            [landing_page] => BILLING
            [shipping_preference] => GET_FROM_FILE
            [user_action] => PAY_NOW
            [return_url] => 
            [cancel_url] => 
        )
)
```

What data should I send in order capture? 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders//capture'. As currently, I am not sending any data in order capture.

I am using above 2 apis to do checkout and pay both seller and parter. But Only seller is getting full amount, partner is not getting anything!

If have hoped on this kind of issue, please suggest me a solution.

Comment: It seems that we have the same problem. You need to get Partner Onboarding even for a Sandbox account - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/partner-onboarding/